# typescript querySelector wrapper

Tags: typescript, types

I have created in typescript this wrapper for `document.querySelector()`:

```js
function qs(selector: string) {
  const elm = document.querySelector(selector)
  if (!elm) throw new Error(`'${sel}' is not in dom`)
  return elm
}

const canvas = qs('canvas')

canvas.getContext('2d')
```

Of course I get `error TS2339: Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'Element'` on last line

Is there a way to make `qr()` return type depends of the `selector` argument like `querySelector()` does?

I tried this:

```js
function qs<T extends Parameters<typeof document.querySelector>[0]>(
  selector: T
): ReturnType<typeof document.querySelector<typeof selector>> {
  return document.querySelector(selector)
}
```

But I get these errors:

```
error TS2344 Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Element'.
error TS2344 Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'HTMLElementTagNameMap'.
error TS2344 Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'SVGElementTagNameMap'.
```

In others words, I want the variable `canvas` to be of type `HTMLCanvasElement` without to have to do:

```
const canvas = qs('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard (if not impossible to do feasibly?) to change the return type of `querySelector` so that it doesn't return null because it has overloads... so here's my workaround:

```
type Qs = {
    <K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(selectors: K): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K];
    <K extends keyof SVGElementTagNameMap>(selectors: K): SVGElementTagNameMap[K];
    <E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): E;
};

const qs: Qs = (selector: string) => {
  const elm = document.querySelector(selector)
  if (!elm) throw new Error(`'${selector}' is not in dom`);
  return elm
}
```

which is literally copying the type of `querySelector` but removing `null` from the return type.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2zozw)

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly! but Im' not sure to understand the first declaration. Is this an object declaration? (`type Qs = { … }`)

Comment: @Yukulélé Yes, it's an object type with call signatures. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures

Comment: thank you so much for that perfect answer! You should probably be able to help me with step 2 of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74204652/typescript-map-queryselector-on-an-object-of-selectors 